# ASP.NET MVC 3 ModelBinder with string sanitizing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to allow incoming HTML in string parameters in my projects action methods, so we have disabled Input Validation.  I have a good HTML sanitizer; the review I am interested in is the way I bound it into my project.

I have the following Model Binder:

```
    public class EIMBaseModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var boundValue = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
            return bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(string) ? HtmlCleaner.SanitizeHtml((string)boundValue) : boundValue;
        }

        protected override void SetProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, object value)
       {
            if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
              var stringVal = value as string;
              value = stringVal.IsNullOrEmpty() ? null : HtmlCleaner.SanitizeHtml(stringVal);
            }

            base.SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, value);
       }
    }
```

I set it as my DefaultBinder in my set up and require that all custom model binders inherit from it. I know I can't completely defend against developers not following this rule, but we are a small team so I think we can police that well enough.

I have some basic unit testing pushing both string primitive values and strings as property values through the binder and those work as expected.  I will be asking the security team to do some penetration tests.

Can anyone see either a better way to have hooked into the incoming data or a base I have missed?

Comment: I've rolled back Rev 3 → 2, for editing away an issue that was helpfully pointed out in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Can't comment on whether there is a better way or a better place in the framework to do this but some general remarks:

1. This doesn't make much sense: `stringVal.IsNullOrEmpty()` - should be `string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringVal)`.
2. You are inconsistent: In the first method you check the type and use a direct cast vs in the second method you check the type and then use `as` - either you trust the type is correct or you don't. Also in `SetProperty` you try to not pass `null` or empty strings to the sanitizer helper while in `BindModel` you don't.
3. It would make sense if the helper method would support `null` and empty strings.

With the above the cleaned up code for `SetProperty` should probably look like this:

```
   protected override void SetProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, object value)
   {
        if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            value = HtmlCleaner.SanitizeHtml((string)value);
        }

        base.SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, value);
   }
```

Comment: Well I never expected a response to this after 3.5 years...that should be worth a Tumbleweed badge.  Apologies for the stringVal.IsNullOrEmpty; that is a reference to an extension method, which really isn't appropriate in a code review question unless it is central to the issue at hand. Will fix. Will consider the rest of your answer but I haven't looked at that code in Years.

Comment: @MatthewNichols: Just working the zombies :)